# How to replace NAs with values from another column in data.table (Example given)?

Tags: r, data.table

DT is data.table and I want to replace NAs with values from visits column and Expected_DT is desired DT.

```
DT<-data.table(name=c("x","x","x","x"),hour=1:4,count=c(NA,45,56,78),visits=c(14,45,56,78))

name hour count visits
1:    x    1    NA     14
2:    x    2    45     45
3:    x    3    56     56
4:    x    4    78     78
```

This is what I want

```
Expected_DT<-data.table(name=c("x","x","x","x"),hour=1:4,count=c(14,45,56,78),visits=c(14,45,56,78))


   name hour count visits
1:    x    1    14     14
2:    x    2    45     45
3:    x    3    56     56
4:    x    4    78     78
```

Comment: is `count >= visits` always true?

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

1) using `fcoalesce`

```
DT[, count := fcoalesce(visits, count)]
```

2) using `is.na`:

```
DT[is.na(count), count := visits]
```

3) using `fifelse`:

```
DT[, count := fifelse(is.na(count), visits, count)]
```

4) using `set` and using sindri_baldur's comment on `[[` for faster indexing:

```
ix <- DT[is.na(count), which=TRUE]
set(DT, ix, "count", DT[["visits"]][ix])
```

Comment: Can speed up `4)` by replacing `DT[ix, visits]` with `DT[[c(4, ix)]]`

Comment: @sindri_baldur. thanks, this is the first time i am seeing this syntax. if I am not wrong, it will not work if there are more than 1 NAs

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I think the replacement would be `DT[["visits"]][ix]`.  The point is `data.table` has some overhead so with uber fast set() so using list syntax is faster if just extracting some values directly.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `data.table`:

```
DT[is.na(count),  count:=visits]

DT
```

Returns:

```
   name hour count visits
1:    x    1    14     14
2:    x    2    45     45
3:    x    3    56     56
4:    x    4    78     78
```

Answer (score 1):

Some base R solutions

- using `ifelse`

```
DT <- within(DT, count <- ifelse(is.na(count),visits,count))
```

- using `rowSums`

```
DT <- within(DT, count <- rowSums(cbind(is.na(count)*visits,count),na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is a dplyr version to be complete for other users:

```
library(dplyr)

DT %>%
    mutate(count = if_else(is.na(count), visits, count))

  name hour count visits
1    x    1    14     14
2    x    2    45     45
3    x    3    56     56
4    x    4    78     78
```